# How to remap vim-commentary commands?

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-vim-commentary

I have downloaded the vim-commentary plugin for commenting in vim. I was trying to remap the default shortcuts for the plugin so as to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> for commenting and remove commenting (default is `gc`). I was also trying to create a map so that I can comment while being in insert mode.

In my vimrc I wrote this:

```
vnoremap <C-/> gc
inoremap <C-/> <Esc>VgcA
```

The first one isn't doing anything. While the second one stops working after entering the Visual mode. What should I do to correct these remaps?

Comment: I think you need the recursive version of `map` here: When you type `<c-/>` you want it to execute what vim-commentary mapped to `gc` not the built-in `gc` feature.

Comment: @statox Thanks. It worked

Answer (score 2):

The commentary.vim plugin file uses the `<Plug>` notation for mapping.

```
  xmap gc  <Plug>Commentary
  nmap gc  <Plug>Commentary
  omap gc  <Plug>Commentary
  nmap gcc <Plug>CommentaryLine
```

The `xmap` mode is like `vmap`, but excludes Select mode (which is rarely used).

`<Plug>Commentary` and `<Plug>CommentaryLine` are easy-to-understand labels which are mapped elsewhere to less obvious Vim commmands.  As a result, you must use the recursive forms of the map commands.

`<Plug>` is character which is impossible to type, so it acts as a placeholder in recursive maps that shouldn't interfere with anything else.

You should be able to do your visual map like this:

```
xmap <c-/> <Plug>Commentary
```

Your insert mode plugin could be:

```
imap <c-/> <Esc><Plug>CommentaryLineA
```

Also, be aware that `<c-/>` is not a standard terminal control code.  These mappings worked fine in gvim but not with Vim in my konsole terminal.

Comment: thanks for the comment.  I edited my answer with the correct info.

Answer (score 1):

You need the recursive version of map here: When you type `<c-/>` you want it to execute what vim-commentary mapped to `gc` not the built-in `gc` feature.

So your mappings should be:

```
vmap <C-/> gc
imap <C-/> <Esc>VgcA
```

I wrote multiple times on this website that you should always use the non recursive version of map unless you know what you are doing, this is the exception which proves the rule :)

Also you probably want to use [`:h i_CTRL-O`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-O) in your insert mode mapping instead of using `<Esc>` and `A`. Probably something like this (not tested):

```
imap <C-/> <C-o>gc
```